# A canceled task propagates two different types of exceptions, depending on how it is waited. Why?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library, cancellation

I encountered a strange behavior while writing some complex async/await code. I managed to create accidentally a canceled `Task` with a dual (schizophrenic) identity. It can either throw a [`TaskCanceledException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcanceledexception) or an [`OperationCanceledException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.operationcanceledexception), depending on how I wait it.

1. Waiting it with [`Wait`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.wait) throws an `AggregateException`, that contains a `TaskCanceledException`.
2. Waiting it with [`await`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/await) throws an `OperationCanceledException`.

Here is a minimal example that reproduces this behavior:

```
var canceledToken = new CancellationToken(true);
Task task = Task.Run(() =>
{
    throw new OperationCanceledException(canceledToken);
});

try { task.Wait(); } // First let's Wait synchronously the task
catch (AggregateException aex)
{
    var ex = aex.InnerException;
    Console.WriteLine($"task.Wait() failed, {ex.GetType().Name}: {ex.Message}");
}

try { await task; } // Now let's await the same task asynchronously
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"await task failed, {ex.GetType().Name}: {ex.Message}");
}

Console.WriteLine($"task.Status: {task.Status}");
```

Output:

```
task.Wait() failed, TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
await task failed, OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
task.Status: Canceled
```

[Try it on Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/J5ZYUm).

Can anyone explain why is this happening?

P.S. I know that the `TaskCanceledException` derives from the `OperationCanceledException`. Still I don't like the idea of exposing an async API that demonstrates such a weird behavior.

---

**Variants:** The task below has a different behavior:

```
Task task = Task.Run(() =>
{
    canceledToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
});
```

This one completes in a `Faulted` state (instead of `Canceled`), and propagates an `OperationCanceledException` with either `Wait` or `await`.
This is quite puzzling because the [`CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken.throwifcancellationrequested) method does nothing more than throwing an `OperationCanceledException`, according to the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/threading/CancellationToken.cs.html#d2864d73804288fc)!

Also the task below demonstrates yet another different behavior:

```
Task task = Task.Run(() =>
{
    return Task.FromCanceled(canceledToken);
});
```

This task completes as `Canceled`, and propagates a `TaskCanceledException` with either `Wait` or `await`.

I have no idea what's going on here!

Comment: This seems to boil down to "`await` and `.Wait()` don't behave the same" - indeed, they don't, but that's not a problem because you should basically *never call `.Wait()`*; as for `OperationCanceledException` vs `TaskCanceledException` - yup; so: just `catch` the first, which handles both (via inheritance) - also just to note: when I say: when I say "never call `.Wait()`", please don't conclude "oh, OK, I'll use `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` instead" - that is not the salient point; the point is *use `await`*

Comment: The line at fault is probably [this one](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Task.cs,1822) -- `Task.Wait()` has to throw a new `TaskCanceledExeption` in this case for back compat concerns, which explains how your `OperationCanceledException` is being turned into a `TaskCanceledException`

Comment: @MarcGravell since you mentioned it, the `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` behaves like the `await`, and so it behaves differently than the `Wait`.

Comment: @canton7 good find! So this is probably an issue caused by backward compatibility requirements.

Comment: even though i am late to the mark, https://github.com/dotnet/corert/blob/c6af4cfc8b625851b91823d9be746c4f7abdc667/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs#L1793

Comment: @TheGeneral Yep, seem my link above

Comment: indeed; the awaiter API didn't need to maintain the back-compat that @canton7 has kindly linked to - so it doesn't - and the awaiter API is *basically* what `await` uses under the covers, but with the important distinction that it is only expected to be called *once the operation has completed* (whether with success or failure); what you're doing here (whether via `.Wait()` or `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`) is "sync over async", and is almost always a terrible idea

Comment: @canton7 yup, indeed nice find. i was running around trying to find the git source :P

Comment: @MarcGravell please note that I posted this question from the perspective of the API developer. I have no idea if the users of my API will use it synchronously or asynchronously. My job is to ensure that my API will function correctly either way, and that its behavior will be consistent.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias if a consumer uses your async API synchronously, **that's on them** - that is called "doing it wrong", and any consequences are now officially their problem, not yours; there is no correct way of synchronously consuming an asynchronous API

Comment: This isn't your API at fault -- this is how the `Task` machinery works. But, throw a `TaskCanceledException` and everything should be fine, no?

Comment: @MarcGravell actually the API I am authoring is similar to the `Parallel.ForEachAsync` API, in that it quite possible to propagate more than one exceptions. So the users of my API could attempt to `Wait` the `Task` after its completion (after having `await` it), to propagate all the exceptions. I see nothing inherently wrong with that. In any case my job is not to educate the users of my API of how to use async/await correctly. That's a job for others (book authors, MVP evangelists etc). I just want to make the life of the users easier, that's all.

Comment: @canton7 throwing a `TaskCanceledException` indeed solves the inconsistency problem, but it's awkward because the `TaskCanceledException` constructor expects a `Task` argument. And I don't have a canceled `Task` at hand. I am inside a `catch` block, and all I have is an `OperationCanceledException` that has been caught by the `catch`. This is an easier solution to my problem: `return Task.FromCanceled(ex.CancellationToken);`

Comment: @TheodorZoulias The `Task` parameter is optional however -- you can just pass in `none`. But yes, if you have a `CancellationToken`, use `Task.FromCanceled`

Answer (score 3):

Summarising multiple comments, but:

- `Task.Wait()` is a legacy API that pre-dates `await`
- for historic reasons, `.Wait()` would manifest cancellation as `TaskCanceledException`; to preserve backwards compatibility, `.Wait()` *intervenes* here, to expose *all* `OperationCanceledException` faults as `TaskCanceledException`, so that existing code continues to work correctly (in particular, so that existing `catch (TaskCanceledException)` handlers continue to work)
- `await` uses a different API; `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`, which behaves more like you would expect and want (although it is not expected to be used until the task is known to have completed), BUT!
- in reality, you should almost never use `.Wait()` or `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`, preferring `await` in almost all cases - see "sync over async"
- if you're *consuming* an async API, and you choose (for whatever reason) to use `.Wait()` or `GetAwaiter().GetResult()`, then *you are stepping into danger*, and any consequences are now entirely your fault as the consumer; this is *not* something that a library author can, or should, compensate for (other than providing twin synchronous and asynchronous APIs)
- in particular, note that while you might get away with subverting the awaiter API with `Task[<T>]`, this pattern with various other awaitables would be an undefined behaviour (to be honest, I'm not sure it is really "defined" for `Task[<T>]`)
- equally: any deadlocks caused by "sync over async" (usually sync-context related) are entirely the problem of the consumer invoking a synchronous wait on an awaitable result
- if in doubt: `await` (but equally, only `await` once; using `await` multiple times is *also* an undefined behaviour for awaitables other than `Task[<T>]`)
- for your exception handling: prefer `catch (OperationCanceledException)` over `catch (TaskCanceledException)`, since the former will handle both via inheritance

Comment: Thanks @MarcGravell for the answer. It contains useful info, but I can't accept it as is, because it is too broad in regard to the question I've asked. For example my question is specific about the `Task` type, not about any kind of awaitable in general!

Comment: @TheodorZoulias that's up to you, but ... honestly, the rules of async don't change *much* for `Task[<T>]` (vs other awaitables) - the difference between "this behaviour is undefined" and "this behaviour is still undefined, but right now for your specific case it'll behave like {this}, and you still shouldn't do it" is ... kinda small; likewise, the question was "Can anyone explain this strange async/await behavior?" - I believe we have, collectively, explained it and offered lots of additional guidance on how/why it isn't actually an interesting problem in any useful scenario

Comment: Marc it's a safe bet that the `TaskAwaiter.GetResult` method will keep its current behavior until the retirement of the .NET platform. Microsoft is extremely averse at doing backward-incompatible changes, and changing the behavior of `TaskAwaiter` to throw if the `GetResult` is invoked more than once, or before the `Task` is completed, would cause a huge number of released async-enabled applications to break instantly.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias it would cause some number of applications that *use the async API incorrectly and in ways that are contrary to the published contract* to break instantly, which isn't quite the same thing, but yes: there is a strong aversion to breaking changes; this isn't absolute

Comment: See e.g. the [list of breaking changes for .NET 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/6.0#core-net-libraries). The chance of actually being bitten by any of those is low, but they do happen

Comment: Marc I could bet 1000 rep points that 15 years from now nothing will have changed with how the `TaskAwaiter.GetResult` behaves. But honestly, if we take into account the points we currently have, it would not be a fair bet!  Btw the [`async Main`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-7.1/async-main) entry point feature has been implemented as `public static void Main() => MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();`, so changing the behavior of the `TaskAwaiter.GetResult` would have a really **big** impact!

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I hear what you're saying, and my position remains the same; `async Main()` is a *bit* of an unusual case, relating to background vs non-background thread semantics and process lifetime, which is why in the answer I left a *tiny* bit of wriggle room via "almost never"; I am absolutely certain that this wriggle room does not apply to your scenario, and that any attempt to do so is just creating a huge future problem

Comment: Marc btw I think that the answer to my question has been given by canton7 in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69552580/can-anyone-explain-this-strange-async-await-behavior/69552953?noredirect=1#comment122937115_69552580), and also by TheGeneral in another comment. I may post that link, and some of the code it links to, as an answer myself, if no one else does. Honestly when I posted this question my desire was to get a logical explanation to a narrow technical observation, not to initiate a discussion (as interesting is it may be) about the right and wrong usage of async-await.